# redirect to m. or www. subdomains if not specified but keep subdomain if entered manually

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, subdomain

When a visitor enter a domain name without prefixing it with "www." or "m.", I would like to redirect it to the "m." subdomain if he's browsing with a handheld device and to the "www." (so-called "desktop version") else.

However, if the users prefixes the domain with "www." or "m.", I would like to respect his choice. The idea is that the editor of the website can still read the mobile or desktop version, whichever the device he uses (mobile or pc) but the concept is extented to any visitor.

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#AllowOverride all

# Force “m.domain.com” for mobile devices instead of just “domain.com”
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://m.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force “www.domain.com” instead of just “domain.com”
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

- The "www." or "m." choice is respected on both desktop and mobile
  device.
- The default redirection from "domain.com" to www.domain.com
  works on PC.
- Unfortunately, the default redirection from "domain.com" to
  "m.domain.com" doesn't work on my smartphones, where the address
  remains on http://domain.com (and hence nothing displays).

The website itself is running on a shared hosting (at Infomaniak) with two subdomains.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing ?